# Need help modifying Magento Shipping Extension

Tags: shipping

I'm looking to change the front end output of this flat rate shipping extension. It outputs a value no matter what the input field is set too (field is available under General, for each product, to add a fee, you would enter 6.95, 10.00, etc..). If field is empty, it outputs $0.00, which to a customer may mean free shipping. I'd like it output "Not Available" or to not show at all if this field is not populated. I have no idea how to achieve the output i need. Thanks!

```
 public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {           
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }
        $shippingPrice =0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
      if($product->getTypeId()=='configurable' || $product->getTypeId()=='bundle') {
        continue;
      }
                $shipCost= $product->getShipCost();                         
            if($shipCost==null || $shipCost==0)
            {
                $shippingPrice += $item->getQty() * $this->getConfigData('price');                       
                }
                    else{
                                $shippingPrice += $item->getQty() * $shipCost;  
                    }
            }
        }                   
            $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');           
            if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
                $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
                $method->setCarrier('flatrateperproduct');
                $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                $method->setMethod('flatrateperproduct');
                $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));  
                $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
                $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
                $result->append($method);
                       }
            return $result; 
}
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
        return array('flatrateperproduct'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
}
```